# Combine "folder as GET parameter" and "subdomain as GET parameter"

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that rewrites path after domain to a `page` GET parameter.

```
##REWRITING DIRECTORIES TO GET PARAMETERS
RewriteBase /
#Ignore all real directories (do not rewrite them)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Also do not rewrite real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#For everything else, index.php should fetch the proper content
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

##This means:
#example.com/help
#~becomes~
#example.com?page=help
```

The site uses multiple languages and so far, I've been using cookies to set and remember the language for the user. While the convenience for the user is disputable, this is definitely not convenient for the [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).

I need to rewrite `[a-z]{2}\.mydomain\.xx` to `index.php?lang=$1` so that user will be always on `en.domain.com` for example. There are examples to do this, however I'm still confused about how the rewrite engine works and I don't know how should I combine my new rules with the old ones:

```
##Language rewrite
#Copypasted. Didn't understand
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{1,2})\.domain\.xx
RewriteRule ([a-z]{1,2})\.domain\.xx index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I get `en.domain.com/help` turn in `index.php?page=help&lang=en`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get en.domain.com/help turn in index.php?page=help&lang=en

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Ignore all real directories (do not rewrite them)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Also do not rewrite real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#For everything else, index.php should fetch the proper content
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{1,2})\.domain\.xx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=%1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Hello, I finally got to test this and it doesn't work. It actually doesn't rewrite anything - I got stuck on main page with default language... Additionally I suspect that this will fail when no language subdomain is specified.

Comment: This is fully tested rule on my Apache. What is exact URL did you enter in your browser? What is this .htaccess located? Are there more rules before this?

Comment: I have mapped `domain.xx` and `en.domain.xx` to localhost. I have configured Apache to create virtual host for this url. Then I have entered `http://en.domain.xx`. I ended up on main page in Czech language. When I enter `http://en.domain.xx/contact`, English main page appears. However, if I split your rule into two, it works.

Comment: Actually you can change regex a bit to match landing page also e.g. `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?lang=%1&page=$2 [QSA,L]`

Comment: @anubhava please help me in this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165325/manage-yii-projects-from-sub-domains-in-var-www-html-folder-htaccess :-)